# bundler no longer vendoring gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have a gem that is a reference to a private repo that I use. I reference it in my gem file like this:

```
gem 'google', git: 'git@github.com:radiumsoftware/google.git'
```

and in my Gemfile.lock the dependency looks like this:

```
GIT
  remote: git@github.com:radiumsoftware/google.git
  revision: dff0e3dcddbfd74967b3a0f954922fd3592b5101
  specs:
    google (0.3.0)
      activesupport
      faraday (~> 0.8.0)
      faraday_middleware
      mail-xoauth
      multi_json
      nokogiri
```

The gem had previously been vendoring, that is it was in my vendor/cache.

I updated the repo for this Gem and changed to the revision to the new commit but after running bundle install or even bundle update, the gem had moved from vendor/cache to the rvm gems folder.

Can anyone explain why?  I am running:

```
bundler 1.6.2
ruby 2.0.0p353
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `bundle package --all` to include git (and path) gems in `vendor/cache`.

http://bundler.io/man/bundle-package.1.html#GIT-AND-PATH-GEMS